# Zsh completion script found but not executed

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

First, let's assume that I have:

```
alias foo='path/to/my/program'
```

in my `.zshrc`, then I created a completion script `~/.oh-my-zsh/completions/_foo` for it, where inside the file I have:

```
#compdef foo

_foo() {
    echo "hello"
}

_foo
```

So, I expected that when I type `foo [tab]` from shell I will see

```
$foo [tab]
hello
```

but instead I got

```
$ foo [tab]_foo
```

The text `_foo` was just printed out after I pressed `tab`.

Do you have any idea for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer about zsh in general. I don't know oh-my-zsh.

By default, zsh expands aliases before attempting completion. This is usually the right thing. As a consequence, associating a completion function to the name of an alias only has an effect when you bypass the alias, for example after `\foo` <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can turn off this behavior with [`setopt complete_aliases`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-COMPLETE_005fALIASES). But you'll lose completion for all aliases for which you don't set up completion explicitly.

If you want to have a special case for `foo`, the best way is to make it a function instead.

```
function foo {
  path/to/my/program "$@"
}
```

This doesn't explain why `_foo` is printed. Maybe some oh-my-zsh weirdness.